# Can I install 512 gb micro sd card in Samsung S9 plus?

Tags: sd-card

Can I install 512 gb micro sd card in Samsung S9 plus ?

Answer (score 1):

The [specifications](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s9+-8967.php) of the phone shows that the phone is able to handle up to 1 TB.

> microSD, up to 1 TB (uses shared SIM slot)

That means yeas you can install a 512 GB microSD card on that phone.

Comment: @user374252 Even on your link, it shows that you can used a 512 GB SD card

Comment: Samsung India website keeps saying its 400 gb max also flipkart and amazon says the same... that's why the confusion came

Comment: Anyway I appreciate ur answer thanks you ; )